# AS3 - Type not found or is not a compile-time constant

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First, before referring me to other posts, I've been looking for a good solution but couldn't figure it out. YES, I have searched, but it didn't help me so I decided to post it here since people here are really smart.

So, I started on making a part for a game in AS3. Since I'm not good with graphics etc. I started first with the AS3 code rather than the flash loader etc. and I tested out connection between AS3 and C# (with sockets).

First frame AS3:

```
import flash.net.Socket;
import Composer;

var sock:Socket = new Socket();
sock.connect("127.0.0.1", 30000);
sock.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderIOErrorHandler);
sock.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);

function loaderIOErrorHandler(errorEvent:IOErrorEvent):void{
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + errorEvent);
}

function connectHandler(event:Event):void{
    var msg:Composer = new Composer("HELLO_WORLD");
    msg.writeDouble(new Date().milliseconds);
    sock.writeBytes(msg.toMessageFormat());
}
```

This is Composer.as (in same folder):

```
package  {

    class Composer {

        private var _arr:ByteArray;

        public function Composer(header:String){
            _arr = new ByteArray();
            _arr.writeUTF(header);
        }

        public function writeUTF(utf:String):void{
            _arr.writeUTF(utf);
        }

        public function writeInt(i:int):void{
            _arr.writeInt(i);
        }

        public function writeShort(i:int):void{
            _arr.writeShort(i);
        }

        public function writeFloat(f:Number):void{
            _arr.writeFloat(f);
        }

        public function writeDouble(d:Number):void{
            _arr.writeDouble(d);
        }

        public function writeBoolean(b:Boolean):void{
            _arr.writeBoolean(b);
        }

        public function writeByte(b:int):void{
            _arr.writeByte(b);
        }

        public function toMessageFormat():ByteArray{
            var msg:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            msg.writeDouble(_arr.length);
            msg.writeBytes(_arr);
            return msg;
        }

    }

}
```

And I always get the error:

'Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant'

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very top of your Composer.as after `package {`, you have to import any classes you reference, otherwise you'll get this error.

Here's what you're missing

```
package  {
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    class Composer {
```